# Understanding ともされる

Tags: grammar

> 声優はデビューしてから3年目まではジュニアランクーーいわゆる新人声優として認識される。
>
> ジュニアランクはアニメや映画の吹き替えなどは一本につき1万5千円に固定されているらしい。
>
> 起用する側は安く使えるために重宝するが、3年経つとランクがどんどん上がっていく。
>
> それはギャラが上がる**ともされる**が、起用する側はその分予算を多くしなければならない。
>
> 仮に同じぐらいの実力の声優がいて、それぞれのランクが違ったら安い方を使うだろう。
>
> だからこそ、ジュニアランクの時は仕事がたくさんあったのに、今じゃ全然……という声優も少なくないらしい。

Does the underlined ともされる mean "be regarded as" in this context? If it does, what role does the も play here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's とされる ("to be widely considered/believed") + も ("also"). も is used to add the sense of contrast to the latter half of the sentence ("on one hand, ...").

But I would say this usage of とされる is not very natural. It's better to say ギャラが上がる機会ともされる, ギャラが上がるとも言える or それはギャラが上がるという意味でもある.